# Connecting Nexus 4 to adb shows no devices

Tags: android, adb

My LG Nexus 4 would not show properly in adb devices eventhough I have udev rules and I run adb server as root. (On ubuntu 13.04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that I have the device connected to USB hub (USB 2.0) connected to USB 3.0 so device wont connect properly, if that is the case check the usb-devices command if it gives any errors and if so **connect the device directly to USB 3.0.**